# How can I convert a file full of unix time strings to human readable dates?

Tags: perl, bash, unix-timestamp

I am processing a file full of unix time strings. I want to convert them all to human readable.

The file looks like so:

```
1153335401
1153448586
1153476729
1153494310
1153603662
1153640211
```

Here is the script:

```
#! /bin/bash
FILE="test.txt"
cat $FILE | while read line; do
perl -e 'print scalar(gmtime($line)), "\n"'
done
```

This is not working. The output I get is **Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970** for every line. I think the line breaks are being picked up and that is why it is not working. Any ideas? I'm using Mac OSX is that makes any difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ perl -lne 'print scalar gmtime $_' test.txt
Wed Jul 19 18:56:41 2006
Fri Jul 21 02:23:06 2006
Fri Jul 21 10:12:09 2006
Fri Jul 21 15:05:10 2006
Sat Jul 22 21:27:42 2006
Sun Jul 23 07:36:51 2006
```

Comment: A few good answers. I had to give it to gbacon though. This one liner worked a treat. 

Thanks to all for the help. It would have been better if I didn't mix bash and perl.

Comment: golfed: `perl -lpe '$_=gmtime$_' test.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Because `$line` is in single quotes, it's not being processed by bash, and so `$line` is treated as an (undefined) Perl variable rather than a bash variable.

You don't need a `while read` bash loop; Perl can do the looping itself using its `-n` option.

```
perl -nE 'say scalar(gmtime($_))' test.txt
```

(using -E to enable `say`, which automatically appends a newline)

Comment: or `-lne` for pre-5.10 versions of Perl

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `cat`.

```
#! /bin/bash
file="test.txt"
while read line
do
    date -d @$line
done < "$file"
```

Comment: I have used to fighting `cat` as you but I ceases. I have found it very practical in command line work. `cat foo | grep bar | ...` seems better that `<foo grep bar | ...` and is more flexible than `grep bar foo | ...`

Comment: If you want to get a Useless Use of Cat award, you can't avoid cat.

Comment: @brian: I have a shelf full of them.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the line breaks, it's that the `$line` inside the Perl script is a different variable than the `$line` in the bash script. You could try:

```
perl -e "print scalar(gmtime($line)),qq/\\n/"
```

Note the double-quotes, which allow bash to do variable interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

No need for Perl:

```
awk '{ print strftime("%c", $0) }' somefile.txt
```

Comment: There's no need for awk either. The Perl solution and your awk solution are basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you haven't assigned anything to the `$line` variable, so it defaults to a zero-value, which is why you always get *Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 1970* as an output.

[gbacon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849753/processing-a-file-full-of-unix-time-strings-to-human-readble/2849786#2849786) is about as slick as it gets in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

GNU date/xargs solution:

```
  xargs -i  date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 {} seconds"  </tmp/timestamps
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple command will do

```
 cat time.txt | while read line; do date -ud @$line; done > string.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Not forgetting that localtime() can be used instead of gmtime() in Perl

So, if you're not in Greenwich in Winter, you can use localtime(), e.g.

Perl code:

```
    my $unixtime = 1417014507;
    my $humantime = localtime($unixtime);
    print "\$humantime = $humantime \n";
```

output:

```
    $humantime = Wed Nov 26 15:08:27 2014
```