# Why does Hyperion's Trunc(date) return large number?

Tags: business-intelligence, truncate, hyperion

I am working with Hyperion and I have never used it before about two weeks ago. Someone else set up a .bqy file to get certain columns from a DB. He has one column with this formula in it: `Trunc(date)` where date included the date and time.

What that column shows, though, is not the date. It shows large numbers like this: `1,377,826,863,000`. They all end in `000`.

What are those numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably milli-seconds since the Epoch of 1/1/1970 with a resolution of 1 second, hence the 3 zeroes at the end. See Wikipedia article for "Unix Time" [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

You can convert to a string, using one of the methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849753/how-can-i-convert-a-file-full-of-unix-time-strings-to-human-readable-dates).

Comment: I think you may be right! Do you know how to convert a date to Unix Time with an equation? I need to convert it to a Crystal Report.

Comment: By the way, you can use the command "date +%s" to get the current Unix time, which stands at 1387788995 as I write this.